# Possible ways of programmatically/normally securing settings tab on lenovo tablet? (Includes android programs to password protect it)

Tags: android, security, configuration

I would like to secure settings tab on lenovo tablet device with a password. What is a simple way of going about this? Code is welcome too (I think I might need to code but if you think an google play marketplace app would solve my problem please post your suggestion below).

Edit: I have researched and posted on lenovo forums already which I always do before posting here and it takes them a week just for simple question sometimes to respond. 
Please if iam too vague say so below because -2 does not help me one bit.

Here's more more information for why iam trying to do this:

I work at a K-12 system with high students always testing my wits.
Without the password kids/students can add their own account or change settings for the tablet doing things that could hurt the school system legally (download playboy, using the devices to distribute viruses and malware, and the list goes on

Comment: What is wrong with the question to mark -1? Its a logical question. I hate trolls.

Comment: This is an important matter for work and yes its a programming question so marking -2 does not help. Hence "programs to protect it"

Comment: What have you tried? This community doesn't tend to be friendly to people who haven't researched their own question.  I also really don't understand what you're looking for and why you're looking for it.  Consider editing your answer to provide more relevant details and your own thoughts of how you might proceed.

Comment: Might want to rephrase the question, I was about to flag it as off-topic until you posted those two comments

Comment: Yes - you are too vague.  Settings tab? what does that mean? Are you referring to the Android Settings application? Are you referring to a specific subsection of the Android settings application? are you referring to a Tab in your own app that controls your own application settings? What are you trying to accomplish? Help us to help you

Comment: The android settings application yes excuse me. I do not want students at my work place (K-12 educational insitution) to change the account I use to download marketplace apps with. It will will need to run in the background constantly and present the student with a password if he trys to access the any of the settings (we have techs already that will know the password if they need into settings).

Comment: Without the password kids/students can change add their own account or change settings for the tablet doing things that could hurt the school system legally (download playboy, using the devices to distribute viruses and malware, and the list goes on).

Comment: @jeffery Thank you! now I can give a meaningful answer - move your comments up into the question body and I'll remove my downvote and vote to close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately for the purposes of what you're doing, Android doesn't really allow for keeping the "primary user", so to speak, out of the settings application.  I'm not personally aware of any existing "lock" type applications, but they might exist; you might be better off asking on [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com) for that.

There are a few hack-y type things you can do programmatically, however, without modifying the OS.  The one I've seen work the most effectively for similar tasks is to code a [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) with a `Thread` more or less continuously polling the [`ActivityManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html) for a list of running tasks (`getRunningTasks()`), checking on fixed intervals (perhaps once a second?) then, if the unwanted `Activity` is detected in the foreground (I believe that the Settings app component name is `android.app.Settings`), Launch a Password `Activity`.  If the user successfully authenticates, simply `finish()` the password `Activity`.  Otherwise, start the home activity (effectively clearing the Activity stack) `with an android.action.HOME` intent

Comment: Sounds good. I'm a little rusty on my Java skills but think I can pull off something like that. let me do my research but I think your idea is sound so far

Comment: @jeffery as a warning, the above will have an impact on battery life, but given your use case it seems like an acceptable tradeoff.  It's also not foolproof, with some knowhow a persistent highschooler might be able to reset the tablet to factory settings without going into settings - but something is better than nothing

Comment: Yes, I understand this will be used at the middle school at the moment but could be used at the high school later if they buy tablets. Iam using this method until we get our absolute apps configuration program running for android devices. Jraymond I doubt the high school student would get away with messing up the device because if it gets messed up by a student the last teacher to check it out for the student or the students name will be on a checkout list (they will be handed out by librarian or techs at the schools) so he/she would be responisble (we have a good inventory system).

Comment: I got my absolute apps management program running today but I will keep this in mind for future ventures and thanks JRaymond.

Comment: I went with applock its a great android app available in the android store and does exactly what you said.